# Expression language and navigation query

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, el

I am trying to to get a new web page to load after the client successfully logs in. So the databases is checked for the username and password and then the boolean variable (greetController.greet) is set. In the expression language, I want to allow the user to move to the next web page (index2) if they are successful. Within the command link I have used a rendered attribute so that the redirect should only happen if the boolean variable is true. Below item (1) is showing the following warning,the action value does not match a navigation case outcome. When I run it, it just prints index to screen. I would appreciate if someone can correct my error

Thanks

Expression language(EL)

```html
<h:form>
    <h:commandButton value="login" action="#{greetController.greet}" />
    <h:commandLink rendered="#{greetController.logInSuccessful}"
        (1) **action="index2?faces-redirect=true"** 
        value="Index2" />        
</h:form>
```

faces-config.xml

```html
<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>/greet.xhtml</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>index2</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/index2.html</to-view-id>
        <redirect />
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

Comment: If you're positive you're on JSF2, this may be because the faces-config.xml navigation cases takes precedence over what it finds in-application. The `faces-redirect=true` bit is unnecessary, as you've already specified `<redirect />` in the faces-config. So all you should have there is action="index2"

Comment: Thanks, I gave that ok but it just prints index2 beside the button. Am I using the correct command. h:commandLink executes a command to go to another page right?

Comment: Why don't you just use a `<h:link>`? Why does it need to be a POST-redirect-GET request? Is it absolutely necessary to submit the whole form (and thus trigger all the JSF conversion/validation/etc works) for a simple page-to-page navigation task?

Comment: Thanks, I have followed your advice. However, the problem persists. All that happens is that a link is produced beside the button. This link has the value "index2" and it points to the page I am on currently. What I am trying to achieve is that when the button is pushed it takes me to another page.

Comment: ok so I am just trying to get the simplest case working now with the following -<h:commandButton value="login" action="index2" />. I get a 404 greeter/index2.jsp not found. How do I ensure that index2.html is called and not index2.jsp? Thanks

Comment: @bosra, you've mixed up so many things here. In this one question, you're referencing `index2.html`, `index2.jsp`, `index2.xhtml`. Which is it?

Comment: @kolossus Thanks mate. I have sorted it now. Easiest solution was to just return a string URL from the bean..Thanks all